# Ubuntu 18.04 won't boot to desktop after update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, wine, steam

AMD 390x connected to monitor via display port.

Haven't booted into my ubuntu partition for a while. The only thing I had installed was Steam, Steam for linux, wine, and this [Padoka PPA](https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/pkppa)

Booted it up, decided to run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Afterwards it said it needed to reboot...

Before rebooting, I also installed from the package manager:

- various desktop wallpapers from previous ubuntu releases via terminal
- Dropbox
- KeepassXC
- KeepassXC snap (by accident, then removed it)
- Qbitorrent

I also installed Brave Browser via (per their site):

```
curl https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-core.asc | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ `lsb_release -sc` main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release-`lsb_release -sc`.list

sudo apt update

sudo apt install brave-browser
```

Then when I went to open Brave browser, everything locked up and the screen made a bunch of graphical glitches. I hard rebooted and it just kept showing the Ubuntu loading screen ("Ubuntu" with the 5 or so dots beneath it). It would show this screen, then go black and do this about 5 times. Ultimately ending in a bunch of static on the screen (graphical glitch) and I'd have to hard reboot it.

Tried rebooting it 3 times, same thing each time. I booted into windows 7 from grub just fine so it's not hardware.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try booting from an older kernel at the GRUB menu.

Comment: I don't know that the kernel updated (last updated Ubuntu about 3 months ago) but I'll try it. I'll be disappointed if that's what broke it

Comment: I have a few kernels to choose from: 4.15.0.36 4.15.0.34 4.15.0.33. Also a recovery option for each. The 4.15.0.34 recovery allowed my to get to my desktop

Comment: Okay well it seems like I can get to my desktop through recovery option of any kernel, but I can't boot straight into any of the "generic" /non recovery kernels. So what is the next step I need to take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of an answer. I removed the padoka ppa and now it boots up fine. So there was some update recently that broke the padoka ppa on Ubuntu 18.04 (for my hardware anyway.